# Handling HTTP headers sent with curl

Tags: php, http, curl, header, http-headers

I'm currently trying to implement oAuth on a server side in order to provide an API for developers. I'm experiencing a very easy issue. I want to be able to handle HTTP headers sent to a script called request.php.

I have no idea how I can do that. I'm a coding a wrapper for clients, and try to make http call on request.php with curl.

```
    $data = array('name' => 'Foo');

    $header = array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100');
    $ch = curl_init("test");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/api/request.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

So, in $headers I received the http responses headers but what I want to do is handling headers received by request.php.

Comment: Please tell us a little bit more - 2 legged or 3-legged, e.g. is end-user going to authorize API access? Which oAuth protocol version are you going to implement - 1.0a or 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

`curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);`

this will cause `$res` in you code to have both the headers and the data seperated by 2 CRLF (4 chars in total as defined in HTTP standards).

HTTP Response example,

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 11782
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 15:07:19 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
(...)
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use curl_getinfo to read headers. 
It is not necessary to set (CURLOPT_HEADER, true) to do this.

For example:

```
    ...
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $response = curl_exec($this->ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($this->ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```